# JSON response handling

Tags: json, extjs, sencha-touch-2

Here is my JSON response for "No record found" reply.When i try to check the "errorMsg" or "response" its not propely working.Here my 
**JSON response**

```
{
"showItems" : 
   [
    {
     "errorMsg" : "NoRecordsFound",
     "response" : "failed"
    }
   ]
}
```

**Condition cheking**

```
 success: function (response) 
 {
  var respObj = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText);
  alert(respObj[0].response);//here it does not retutning anyting
  if(respObj[0].response=="Success")
    {
      Ext.getCmp('itemList').setData(respObj.showItems);
    }
  if(respObj[0].response=="failed")
    {
      Ext.Msg.alert("Alert!","No records found!");
    }
 }
```

How to check the condition?Please help me to solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText) will return
```

[image]

You should access response like this

```
respObj.showItems[0].response
```

**Where**

respObj is the Object

showItems is the Array

response & errorMsg are properties of first item in showItems array.

**Try**

```
success: function (response) 
 {
  var respObj = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText);
  var response=  respObj.showItems[0].response;
  alert(response);
  if(response=="Success")
    {
      Ext.getCmp('itemList').setData(respObj.showItems);
    }
  if(response=="failed")
    {
      Ext.Msg.alert("Alert!","No records found!");
    }
 }
```